# Magento 2.4 FilterSearch Custom admin grid

Tags: grid, custom, filter

I'm trying to modify the admin grid's "filterSearch" field from default query if I type a whole word eg "Iphone", I'm trying to change the type search criteria in SQL to LIKE %ipho% and finding a result with that information is currently not like that.

[image]

[image]
In the previous image I show that if I write "Iphone" it finds a result, but if I write "Ipho" it does not find. I have been looking and the grid of products and clients if it works as I need it.

Can anyone help me out? Please.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <?php
>
>
> namespace MagentoForm\ContactUsModel\Setup;
>
>
> use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
> use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
>
> class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
>
> {
>     public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
>     {
>         $setup->startSetup();
>         if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '0.1.7') < 0) {
>
>             $tableName = $setup->getTable('contactform');
>             $fullTextIntex = array('name' , 'email');
>
>
>             $setup->getConnection()->addIndex(
>                 $tableName,
>                 $setup->getTable($tableName, $fullTextIntex, \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT),
>                 $fullTextIntex,
>                 \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
>             );
>
>
>         }
>
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the indexes are already created, the filterSearch works, what I need is to customize the search criteria, in the images that I uploaded it shows me that if I write an exact word for example "Iphone" it shows me the result, but if I write "ipho" it does not find results, I want to modify it in a way that if I write "ipho" it finds a result similar to an SQL query type LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

1st Step:

In di.xml

in etc/di.xml
Add below code

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
     <arguments>
         <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="customer_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">VendorName\ModuleName\Model\GridJoinCollection</item>
         </argument>
     </arguments>
 </type>
```

2nd Step:

extend class \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection in your custom class

```
class GridJoinCollection extends \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection{
 public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
}
```

and add custom filter in addFieldToFilter()

3rd Step:

```
 namespace VendorName\MdouleName\Model;
 
 use Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\DataProvider\Document;
 use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
 use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
 use Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface;
 use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;
 use Zend_Db_Expr;
 
 class GridJoinCollection extends \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection
 {
     /**
      * @inheritdoc
      */
     protected $document = Document::class;
 
     /**
      * Initialize dependencies.
      *
      * @param EntityFactory $entityFactory
      * @param Logger $logger
      * @param FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy
      * @param EventManager $eventManager
      * @param ResolverInterface $localeResolver
      * @param string $mainTable
      * @param string $resourceModel
      */
     public function __construct(
         EntityFactory $entityFactory,
         Logger $logger,
         FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
         EventManager $eventManager,
         ResolverInterface $localeResolver,
         $mainTable = 'customer_grid_flat',
         $resourceModel = '\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer'
     ) {
         $this->localeResolver = $localeResolver;
         parent::__construct($entityFactory, $logger, $fetchStrategy, $eventManager, $localeResolver, $mainTable, $resourceModel);
     }

     /**
      * Modify for custome
      */
     public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
     {
         if ($field === 'custome') {
          $connection = $this->getConnection();
            return $connection->prepareSqlCondition('customer_entity_table.password_hash', ['notnull' => true]);
         }
 
     }
```

}

Comment: @Ronals Please let me know if you face any issue.